# How is the RoutedCommand.Name property used?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, routed-commands

The [`RoutedCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.aspx) class has a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.routedcommand.name.aspx) property that can be set in the contructor. MSDN has this to say about `RoutedCommand.Name`:

> This property can be used when referencing a RoutedCommand in XAML.

However, I can't seem to find information on how to do this. Currently, my commands are referenced in XAML like this:

```
Command="{x:Static someNamespace:Commands.SomeCommand}"
```

This does does not refer to the command by its `Name` property, and works whether or not you set `Name`.

What is the purpose of `RoutedCommand.Name`, and how can it be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RoutedCommand.Name` literally serves a name of `RoutedCommand` to bind with `DependencyPropery` of some `UIElement`, usually `MenuItem` or `Button`.

Please, refer to the XAML code below, where `ApplicationCommands` class is included in `System.Windows.Input` namespace(PresentationCore.dll).

```
<Button Command="{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}" 
    Content="{Binding Source={x:Static ApplicationCommands.Open}, Path=Name}"/>
```